# Unit Test Functions Connecting to a Postgres DB

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, pg-promise

I am using mocha, nodejs and pg-promise connecting to a Postgres db. I am wondering how can I unit test a function that executes a DML? This is just a simple example:

```
export function insertUser(db, { firstName, lastName }) {
  db.one(`
    INSERT INTO users
    (
      firstName,
      lastName
    )
    VALUES
    (
      $<firstName>,
      $<lastName>
    )
  `, { firstName, lastName });
}
```

If there is a typo in the query, how can the unit test capture it? I can create a test db, creating temporary tables on the fly but this will cause my test to slow down.

Comment: Usage example: https://coderwall.com/p/axugwa/cleaning-the-database-in-between-mocha-tests-with-pg-promise

Comment: @vitaly-t - I can see several issues with this approach. First, it will slow down unit test since it will connect to DB. Second, it will be harder to maintain since we need to create a new test database that is the exact replica of the main database. Third, it is like we are testing pg-promise functionality. In unit testing, we assumed that pg-promise is properly tested on its own so there is no need to test its functionality.

Comment: Modern testing for database code requires a good isolation, which means using such systems as Travis CI, which gives you a fresh database for each of your PR-s, which is the way to go. And if you run tests locally, they are not slow at all, they are very fast, I do it all the time. Also, no idea what you mean by `it is like testing pg-promise functionality`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the db variable is a function parameter, unit-testing this type of code will be straight-forward.

Go ahead and install a mocking library. We have had good success with [sinonjs](http://sinonjs.org/).

```
npm install sinon --save-dev
```

With the mock library in place you can now create the unit-test, something along the lines as follows:

```
const should = require('should'),
      sinon = require('sinon'),
      helper = require('your-db-module');

describe('DB functions', () => {
  describe('insertUser', () => {
    const { insertUser } = helper;

    it('correctly inserts a new user', () => {
      const db = {
        one: sinon.stub()
      };

      insertUser(db, { firstName: 'john', lastName: 'doe' });

      db.one.calledWithExactly('INSERT INTO users(firstName, lastName) VALUES($<firstName>, $<lastName>)', { firstName: 'john', lastName: 'doe'}).should.eql(true);
    });
  });
});
```

That should set you off on the right foot.

Comment: So we need to replicate the query from the code to the test. I was just thinking that with this approach, a developer will simply copy and paste the query from the test to the code. What if I mispelled "INSERT" to "INSET"? How can a unit test catch that error?

Comment: IMHO, you should write the test before you write the function itself to help avoid that. Beyond that you would have 1 or more functionals tests around this area of code to check that things are working as expected. That should be more than adequate test coverage to continue.